# Can I submit a ruby gem I'm working on for ubuntu app showdown?

Tags: application-development, ruby, gem

I've been working on a ruby project, can I submit this for app showdown?
Basically its a sinatra app, runs a site on localhost, which plays songs in browser

Answer (score 1):

Today is the final day to submit your application for the App Showdown (if it has not already closed today). Assuming your application is complete and ready for submission:

As the final step, you’ll get to publish your app in the Software Centre to be distributed to millions and rated and reviewed for the community vote. We ask all participants to package their apps in a Personal Package Archive (PPA), which Quickly makes really easy:

◦ Set up a PPA on Launchpad

◦ Run the following command to package and upload your app:

```
quickly submitubuntu
```

◦ Your application must be published to a PPA, run out of /opt, only have dependencies in the Ubuntu 12.04 archive, and must work correctly.

Fortunately Quickly eases this with the above command. If you choose not to use Quickly and you are manually packaging it, if your application does not adhere to the above points, it will be rejected.

◦ IMPORTANT! While submitting your app, fill in the App Showdown Participation Details and upload it in the ‘Your application‘ field in MyApps.

```
Source: Ubuntu App Developer - http://developer.ubuntu.com/2012/07/ubuntu-app-showdown-deadline-approaching-get-your-submissions-ready/
```